# Objectives in collectible card games

Tags: game-design

The majority of deck building card games use the following winning condition:

- You and your opponent are the central figures on the battlefield, and the game ends as soon as one of you (or both) is killed.
- You start the game with some positive amount of life that goes up and down (usually down) as you battle.
- Whenever your life total is at or below 0, you are dead and you lose.

A slight variety of that is when there is no central figure and you have to destroy all your opponent's creatures to win.

I was able to find only two games that use different winning conditions: Gwent the Witcher and Ascension: Chronicle of the Godslayer. Could you please name some more?

In particular, I'm interested in the following condition: you and your opponent start at 0 points, you earn (or lose) points as you play and whoever has more points at the end of the game wins. (Both Gwent and Ascension seem to be examples of this mechanic.)

Comment: Hi, can you add some more information about the winning conditions of Gwents. So you can get answers from people that do not know the game.

Comment: This seems like a list question, which might be off topic, but some examples might be the Lord of the Rings game (you win if you reach the end of the map; you lose if your ring-bearer dies) and Netrunner (which is completely assymetric)

Comment: Ascension is not a CCG, and it's not 2p-only. Also, there are tons of games with different win conditions. For a strictly card game, look at Innovation.

Comment: For the record I have played plenty of deck building games where killing your opponent is not the goal or a feature of the game. In truth when you start looking there are lots of different win conditions based on the theme of the game.

Answer (score 1):

They are not CCGs strictly speaking but Fantasy Flight Games' Game of Thrones Living Card game and the new Keyforge have very different victory conditions.

The latter has Aember, basically victory points, that can be won, lost and stolen. They are automatically used to unlock keys at the beginning of you turn. When you unlock 3 keys, you win. The game still uses, creatures, artifacts and instants, but all serve to earn Aember.

Killing creatures only slows your opponent down. I like this system a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much every card game from Fantasy Flight has a different victory condition.

Android: Netrunner is played to 7 points.

Legend of the Five Rinds is won militarily by destroying provinces rather than dealing damage, and you can also win on Honor.

Warhammer 40,000: Conquest was a different variant of fighting for provinces, and the central figure (the warlord) was an in-game creature that could be killed (you lost if your warlord died).

Arkham Horror: The Card Game is a game where you play co-op missions and have customization decks of equipment.

The list goes on.